# Cross-platform application (Android, iOS, Symbian)

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I'm developping an HTML5 cross-platform game. Now I'm using Phonegap with the Android sdk. But I want this game to work on iOS. Should I have a Mac and repeat all the work on it, or the game will be working on iOS without all this procedure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PhoneGap doesn't produce one app that can run on different platforms, instead it is used to create an app per platform (each app contains the same version of your HTML5 code). Thus you will have to create an iOS specific version of your app using PhoneGap. This is very quick to do, however you will need a Mac and XCode in order to build the app.

Apple apps also need to be signed with certificates, so you will need to sign up as an iOS developer with the Apple web site and create the necessary certificates.

Comment: tank u much i'm new to this world so this's why i didn't read much about the couple PhoneGap and iOS .So from your explaination i've to install the Mac virtual machine, XCode , eclipse and phoneGap.

Comment: Understanding and creating the certificates is quite confusing, doing this part of things will probably take you longer than converting your existing Android App to an iOS app. I'd recommend looking for a good tutorial on this, use google to find some.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this site to build your application for all plateforms: https://build.phonegap.com/. For generating your iOS application you should have a certofication licence.
Good luck!